# Font awesome 5.13.0 pro not showing icon when including only all.css in gulp angular project

Tags: font-awesome

Font awesome 5.13.0 not showing icon when including only all.css in gulp project but when i include all.js as well it displays the icon but the i tags are converted into svg. Need help please.How can i make it work without converting it to svg.

Folder structure:

[image]

this is how i've included fontawesome

[image]

I checked file in dest folder as well and the fontawesome css are present n that fiile.

but the cons are not being dislayed.

**updated folder structure**

[image]

how it should be displayed

[image]

How it is being displayed

[image]

Comment: The font files are supposed to be at `../webfonts/` relative to the `all.css`, not at `webfonts/`.

Comment: Thank you for response GSerg .So you mean my folder structure is not correct?

Comment: No, your folder structure is not correct. Download the zip from the fontawesome website, it shows the correct structure.

Comment: You now have `all.mn.css` instead of `all.min.css`?

Comment: I updated the folder structure but still its not working. I've added the screenshot of how it should be displayed vs how it is being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Actually i was just adding webfonts folder to assets folder but  i missed to add a gulp task to migrate the files of webfonts folder. So the all.css file was unable to find the webfonts files and thus the icons were not showing up.

Take away here for me (as well as who don't know about this dependency)-

- The in addition to all.css, files in webfonts folder is also also required in order for font awesome to work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working sample with CSS only. If it doesn't work for you, please provide more details.

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you for response @MBaas. but will it work if i have the fontawesome files in assets foler as well? I have edited my question for folder structure as well.

Comment: You still have the wrong path-structure in your gulp.scr-command!

Comment: I'd suggest to check the browser-console for any error-messages or files with 404 status.

Comment: for wrong path in screenshot i have correct path in code. ANd in console there is no error message and the css related to fontawesome are also present destination file created by gulp